# Change all website links to affiliate links automatically

Tags: javascript, web, mediawiki, affiliate

I would like to be able to automatically change links into affiliate links automatically on my **MediaWiki** installation. This would help to reduce the amount of time managing links in case the code needs to be changed in the future.

This is the setup of my GOG.com affiliate scheme: I need to append this key to the end of every GOG.com link: `?pp=708a77db476d737e54b8bf4663fc79b346d696d2`

```
gog.com/en/gamecard/baldurs_gate_the_original_saga/?pp=708a77db476d737e54b8bf4663fc79b346d696d2
```

Is it possible for a piece of code, like Javascript, to intercept all links (like `http://www.gog.com/en/gamecard/baldurs_gate_the_original_saga/`) and append the affiliate code on the end, as in the above example?

I'm aware of this piece of Javascript code called [Amazon Associate Link Localiser](http://petewilliams.info/blog/2009/07/javascript-amazon-associate-link-localiser/) which does a similar thing. However, it only works for Amazon links, and it also localises links which is a feature I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Right way is to use [LinkerMakeExternalLink](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/LinkerMakeExternalLink) mediawiki hook like that ( you can put it at bottom of your LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgHooks['LinkerMakeExternalLink'][] = 'ExampleExtension::exampleLinkerMakeExternalLink';

class ExampleExtension {
    public static function exampleLinkerMakeExternalLink( &$url, &$text, &$link, &$attribs, $linktype ) {
        if( strpos( $url, 'gog.com') !== false ) {
            $url .= '?pp=708a77db476d737e54b8bf4663fc79b346d696d2';
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how great it would be performance wise for hundreds of links.

```
// Plain Javascript

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, max = links.length; i < max; i++) {
    var _href = links[i].href;

    if (_href.indexOf('gog.com') !== -1) {
        links[i].href = _href + '?pp=708a77db476d737e54b8bf4663fc79b346d696d2';   
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bj8La/2/)

Answer (score 0):

So you can also use jquery to bind any link click.  This way you can do your link eval on the fly.  This jsfiddle is a rough run through of what i think you're trying to accomplish.  The alerts are just for your benefit and should be removed.

```
$("a").click(function() {
    addAffiliate(this);
});

myCode = "?pp=708a77db476d737e54b8bf4663fc79b346d696d2";
myAmazonCode = "?tag=shihac-20"
    function addAffiliate(link) {
        alert("enterting script: " + link.href);
        if ((link.href).indexOf("gog.com") > -1 && (link.href).indexOf(myCode) < 0) {
                link.href = link.href + myCode;
        }else if((link.href).indexOf("amazon.com") > -1 && (link.href).indexOf(myAmazonCode) < 0){
                link.href = link.href + myAmazonCode;   
        }
            alert(link.href);
            return true;
        }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/du47b/23/

UPDATE: added code and fully qualified paths

UPDATE: added 'else if' block for other codes. using 'else if' instead of just another if block will hopefully cut back on unnecessary processing.

Comment: Thanks so much, this looks like a very good solution. I am not great at JavaScript. Can you tell me what the best way to add additional codes in? For example, I'd like my amazon.com links to append ?tag=shihac-20 to the end. Do I just copy the

myCodeAmazon ="?tag=shihac-20";

if ((link.href).indexOf("amazon.com") > -1 && (link.href).indexOf(myCode) < 0) {
            link.href = link.href + myAmazoncom;