# Automatically prepend affiliate identifier to URLs

Tags: javascript, php, prepend, affiliate

I would like to automatically add an affiliate identifier to URLs on my website.
For example, I have external URLs such as:

```
https://www.adairs.com.au/

https://bedthreads.com.au/products/caitlin-robson-footed-bowl
```

My affiliate identifier varies based on the retailer, such as:

```
adairs.com.au: https://t.example.com/12345/t/54321?Url=

bedthreads.com.au: https://t.example.com/12121/t/21212?Url=
```

I need these automatically prepended at the beginning of the external URLs upon click to form:

```
https://t.example.com/12345/t/54321?Url=https://www.adairs.com.au/

https://t.example.com/12121/t/21212?Url=https://bedthreads.com.au/products/caitlin-robson-footed-bowl
```

The closest solution I have found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106191/automatically-convert-all-external-links-to-affiliate-links?noredirect=1&lq=1) however I am not very experienced in java and was unable to make it work. Ideally, I would also like to add other automatic affiliate identifiers for other retails in future.

Also, is it possible to add this in PHP?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    // attach a click even to all <a> elements
    $("a").click(function() {
        addAffiliate(this);
    });
    
    // adairs affiliate URL for redirect
    var adairsaffURL = "https://t.example.com/12345/t/54321?Url=";
    // bedthreads affiliate URL for redirect
    var bedthreadsaffURL = "https://t.example.com/12121/t/21212?Url=";
    
    // function called when link is clicked
    function addAffiliate(link) {
        // make sure this link is not to the current site and does not contain the affiliateURL
        if ((link.href).indexOf(adairs.com.au) < 0 && (link.href).indexOf(adairsaffURL) < 0){
            // update the link with the affiliateURL, the url encoded link, and the additional query string
            link.href = affiliateURL + escape(link.href);
        
}else if((link.href).indexOf(bedthreads.com.au) < 0 && (link.href).indexOf(bedthreadsaffURL) < 0){
                link.href = bedthreadsaffURL + escape(link.href);  
        }
        alert(link.href);
        // return true to follow the link
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your idea, I updated your code to let it works. Please `Run code snippet` to see the demo.

You just need to use `.indexOf('adairs.com.au')` to check the link belongs to the affiliate program, so you append it into `affiliate URL`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // adairs affiliate URL for redirect
  var adairsaffURL = "https://t.example.com/12345/t/54321?Url=";
  // bedthreads affiliate URL for redirect
  var bedthreadsaffURL = "https://t.example.com/12121/t/21212?Url=";

  // function called when link is clicked
  addAffiliate = function(link) {
    
    if (link.hash.substr(1).length > 0) return true;
    var redirectUrl = link.href;
    if (!redirectUrl || !isValidURL(redirectUrl)) return true;
    
    if (redirectUrl.indexOf('adairs.com.au') > 0) {
      redirectUrl = adairsaffURL + escape(redirectUrl);
    } else if (redirectUrl.indexOf('bedthreads.com.au') > 0) {
      redirectUrl = bedthreadsaffURL + escape(redirectUrl);
    }
    link.href = redirectUrl;
    return true;
  }

  $("a").click(function(event) {
    addAffiliate(this);
  });

  function isValidURL(string) {
    var res = string.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
    return (res !== null)
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.adairs.com.au/">test adairs</a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="https://bedthreads.com.au/products/caitlin-robson-footed-bowl">test bed threads</a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="http://www.google.com">test not match adairs or bedthreads</a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="#dsdsd">test no link</a>
```

**Update:** function to add to Wordpress. Put the below into your functions.php in your theme.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'auto_affiliate_url');
function auto_affiliate_url()
{ 
?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

      // adairs affiliate URL for redirect
      var adairsaffURL = "https://t.example.com/12345/t/54321?Url=";
      // bedthreads affiliate URL for redirect
      var bedthreadsaffURL = "https://t.example.com/12121/t/21212?Url=";

      // function called when link is clicked
      addAffiliate = function(link) {
        
        if (link.hash.substr(1).length > 0) return true;
        var redirectUrl = link.href;
        if (!redirectUrl || !isValidURL(redirectUrl)) return true;

        if (redirectUrl.indexOf('adairs.com.au') > 0) {
          redirectUrl = adairsaffURL + escape(redirectUrl);
        } else if (redirectUrl.indexOf('bedthreads.com.au') > 0) {
          redirectUrl = bedthreadsaffURL + escape(redirectUrl);
        }
        link.href = redirectUrl;
        return true;
      }

      $("a").click(function(event) {
        addAffiliate(this);
      });

      function isValidURL(string) {
        var res = string.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
        return (res !== null)
  };


    });
</script>

<?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that code looks like it should work. I've tried implementing it into my website but with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: I've tried adding it into footer.php with <script></script> as well as:

 add_action('wp_footer', 'auto_affiliate_url');
function auto_affiliate_url() {
    ?>  // javscript code here  <?php
}

Clicking on URLs after implementing code snippet still do not have the affiliate URL prepended. Am I implementing it incorrectly?

Comment: @KaiH I updated the function to add into wordpress, please put it into your functions.php in your theme folder.

Comment: That's working perfectly now. Thank you for the help, it's very much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I've come across an issue where my pop ups no longer open after implementing this code. I'm using WordPress/Elementor. Any idea how I might avoid this issue?

Comment: @KaiH Is there any errors in console?

Comment: I've checked and there are no errors in console. The below is appended to the URL however, whereas normally the URL would remain unchanged and the popup would display on button click.
#elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjM3NjgiLCJ0b2dnbGUiOmZhbHNlfQ%3D%3D

Comment: @KaiH I updated the code, you can try it again with the `function isValidURL(string)`. Please let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately, having the same issue.

Comment: @KaiH could you show that code for me?

Comment: What would be the best way to show you? I have used the same code as your second example, updated for use in Wordpress, but with the `function isValidURL(string) {
    var res = string.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
    return (res !== null)`

after the

`$("a").click(function(event) {
    addAffiliate(this);
  });`

Comment: @KaiH can you add your website URL here?

Comment: Here is a page of my website with a button to trigger a pop-up, "add custom gift": https://simpleregistry.com.au/gift-ideas/

Comment: @KaiH I add `redirectUrl.indexOf(window.location.hostname)` in the redirect condition. I've tested on your site. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This has fixed the popups, however the affiliate URLs are no longer prepended when clicking on links.

Comment: @KaiH Updated the condition, `redirectUrl.indexOf(window.location.hostname) > 0`. Please try to use it. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Still having the same issue, fixed popup issue but no prepended affiliate URLs.

Comment: @KaiH updated another version.

Comment: No change, unfortunately.