# auto url modifier

Tags: javascript

got a small script from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798336/change-all-website-links-to-affiliate-links-automatically?lq=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798336/change-all-website-links-to-affiliate-links-automatically?lq=1)1 (the second one) to add affiliate tag into url

and this is what i put in the header of my page

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://。。。。。。/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$("a").click(function() {
    addAffiliate(this);
});

myCode = "http://moe.jlist.com/click/99999999?url=";
myAmazonCode = "&tag=99999999"
    function addAffiliate(link) {
        alert("enterting script: " + link.href);
        if ((link.href).indexOf("jlist.com") > -1 && (link.href).indexOf(myCode) < 0) {
                link.href = myCode + link.href;
        }else if((link.href).indexOf("amazon.com") > -1 && (link.href).indexOf(myAmazonCode) < 0){
                link.href = link.href + myAmazonCode;   
        }
            alert(link.href);
            return true;
        }​
</script>
```

however, it is not working, but it works on jsfiddle.net from the url provided by above link when i set the framework to 'onload' with jquery

secondly
i have convert codes from another shopping site that i want to integrate into my codes
this is a sample of wut they gave me

```
    function convert_aff_links( $_body, $_aff_id = '9999999' )
{
    $_body = preg_replace
    (
        '@://(w+\.)?(playasia|play-asia)\.com/?([^/a-zA-Z])@',
        '://www.play-asia.com/SOap-23-' . '83-' . $_aff_id . '-50-00.html$3',
        $_body
    );

    $_body = preg_replace
    (
        '/paOS-(\d{2})/',
        'SOap-23-' . '83-' . $_aff_id . '-50-$1',
        $_body
    );

    return $_body;
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running this too early before the DOM has been loaded, thus there are no `a` tags in the page yet for it to attach to:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("a").click(function() {
    addAffiliate(this);
});
</script>
```

Change it to this so it isn't run until the document has loaded:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        addAffiliate(this);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: tried that, didn't work, don't know why (did clear cache)
even tried to put the code at the end of the page, still didn't work
maybe there is conflict somewhere? or server setting?

Comment: @Randy - This gets your `addAffiliate()` function to run on every clicked link that is present in the page HTML.  Now you may have to figure out why that function isn't doing what you want.  You'd have to tell us more about what is and isn't working and what it's supposed to do for us to know what other advice to offer.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have set up a test on http://jsfiddle.net/KTQ3z/2/ each time i click on the j-list link the alert says it successfully changed url, so i check the affiliate site the counter is updated immediately, it works, but when i do it on my own site, the click counter never get updated, so i know it is not working. i just created a brand new html page with one link and this code in it. the click counter still didn't update (both on and off server), so i assume there is no conflict between my site's code. what is the different between the jsfiddle test scenario and my code?

Comment: @Randy - you've shown us the code that works, but not the code that doesn't work.  Kind of hard for us to know what's different in the code that doesn't work without seeing it.

Comment: http://eudemon.org/Untitled.zip here is an example of page tat doesn't work, note tat the affiliate tag has been changed to prevent abuse (ofc i trust u but someone else might viewing this post as well) ofc when i test it myself i would change to back to the working tag (same as test in jsfiddle, which works)

Comment: @Randy - There are two problems with that test page.  First, you need to use `$(document).ready()`, not `$(document).onload()`.  Second, there is an illegal character following the closing brace of the `addAffiliate()` function.  It generates a script parsing error in the browser so the script doesn't load successfully.  Remove that illegal character and fix the `$(document).ready()` and then it appears to work.

Comment: i was testing the function with onload and forgot to change it back, and sorry but which illegal character are you talking about? if it is the extra space, tried remove, didn't work

Comment: @Randy - whatever character (it's not visible) is after the closing brace for the `addAffiliate()` function.  When I remove that character, the javascript error goes away and the script works.  You should be looking in your browser's error console to see what errors it reports.

Comment: yes! i found that invisible character, it's not taking any space, but i had to press backspace twice to remove }. thank you so much. btw can you help me integrate the second function i posted here into my current code?

Comment: @Randy - Stackoverflow doesn't work well with multiple questions in the same post.  You should ask one question per post, get an answer, accept that answer and then ask a new question.  SO is not meant to be a conversation about multiple issues.  When asking about that second issue in your new question, please describe exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok, thanks, im new to stackoverflow, i will try to work on it myself, if i still have issue i will post a question