# Change all links posted on my ipb forum to affiliate links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, affiliate, ipb

I want to change all the links post by my forum members to my affliate links

like if a member posts a link **site.com** then on click it should get converted into      **site.com/&myaffiliatecode**

this is exactly what I need [Change all website links to affiliate links automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798336/change-all-website-links-to-affiliate-links-automatically) **but the problem is its not working with ipb forum**

I edited the header template and added `<script type="text/javascript" src="source-of-jquery.js"></script>` but the links were not changing on clicks

Comment: show your working code

Comment: $("a").click(function() {
    addAffiliate(this);
});
 
myCode = "&affid=*******";
    function addAffiliate(link) {
        if ((link.href).indexOf("site.com") > -1 && (link.href).indexOf(myCode) < 0) {
                link.href = link.href + myCode;
        }
                    return true;
    }

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798336/change-all-website-links-to-affiliate-links-automatically